# How to restore default icon behavior on MacOS desktop?

Tags: macos

Image showing the problem (icons near bottom):

[image]

Somehow the icons on my Mac got weird. It's not the "Use Stacks" feature. As shown, there is no checkmark next to that option on the popup menu.

I can't figure out how to resolve this. Using MacOS 12.1.

Comment: Try Clean Up...

Comment: @lhf That has no effect.

Comment: Click on the Desktop. Select All. View / Clean Up